# ORDER by ID to get latest records?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

Is it a good idea to order by ID instead of a date field, when I want to get the latest records? It should be faster because the ID is the primary key, but would I always get the latest records?

Comment: The ID may be the primary key, but you can also create indexes for other fields to ensure they are unique, for example.

Comment: This depends on how is the `ID` being calculated. Is it an identity?, is it always ascending?, can people insert `ID` that aren't autmatically calculated?. Basically, you are asking us when we don't know anything about your primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you order by ID and your ID is your identity column it should be fine because you will be ordering from latest to earliest. Just remember to put the results in DESC order.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether the latest one have a bigger Id than earlier ones doesn't it.

It's down to pragmatism this one, if you have complete control over what the id is and you are prepared to take the hit if some future change forced you to change the Id (say from int to string) then I wouldn't criticise you for it.

If you are nervous about being able to rely on it, abstract it out e.g a GetItemsInOrder, method, Stored proc or View type thingy 
That way if the silicon deity refused to smile up on you, you can add a Created_Order column, populate it from ID, amend the thingy to use it and then go ahead with what would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your ID has been auto incrementing it should work faster and in the right order.

If not, adding a "order added" column, assigning a value starting from 0 for the oldest date to whatever number is the newest, have that column auto-increment in the future and sort by that, would still be faster than sorting by date.